# Active Record - query to exclude entries from parent table if any of its children match

Tags: sql, activerecord, has-many-through

Lets say I'm looking at physicians and patients booking appointments together, and I want to filter out appointments that involved a physician with user.id = 1. My physicians and patients are stored in the same class Users (there's a user_roles and roles table to differentiate them but that's not important for this example) and tied to each Appointment through a UserAppointments table, so it looks roughly like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_appointments

class UserAppointment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :appointment

class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :user_appointments
    has_many :users, through: :user_appointments
```

I initially tried something like `Appointment.joins(:users).where.not("users.id = 1")` but any Appointment including user 1 still had a valid patient connected to it, so it would inner join on the patient's UserAppointment entry and include a record of that appointment. Valid appointments appear twice in this query because there are two UserAppointment entries for the two Users.

So I could set up a filter for any Appointment.id that appears twice (indicating that the physician involved wasn't user 1) or create a list of Appointments involving user 1, and filter those out directly. But I'm just wondering if there's a command similar to `.where.not` that could exclude an Appointment if matched any condition, even if it had other valid children that didn't match the condition.

Answer (score 1):

`Appointment.joins(users: :roles).where(roles: {code: :physician}).where.not(users: {id: 1})`

That way you count each appointment once per physician. (Replace `code` with the equivalent column in your `roles` table)

Nevertheless, you seem to say that an appointment is always between a patient and a user. If that's true, the following architecture might be better suited:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :user_appointments

class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :patient, class_name: 'User' # needs a patient_id foreign key
belongs_to :physician, class_name: 'User' # needs a physician_id foreign key
```

Then you can query `Appointment.where.not(physician_id: 1)`

*Edit post comment:*

If you want to get, say, all appointments for patient#10, while excluding appointments with physicians #1 and #2, here's how you could pull it off:

```
class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  scope :joins_physician, -> { joins(users: :roles).where(roles: {code: :physician}) }
  scope :joins_patient, -> { joins(users: :roles).where(roles: {code: :patient}) }
  scope :excluding_physicians, -> (*physician_ids) { where.not(id: unscoped.joins_physician.where(users: {id: physician_ids})) }
  scope :for_patients, -> (*patient_ids) { where(id: unscoped.joins_patient.where(users: {id: patient_ids})) }
end

Appointment.for_patients(1).excluding_physicians(1,2)
```

As you can see, it starts getting weirdly complicated for something that should be simple. The weirdness comes from the model structure not reflecting the business associations between `Appointment`, `User` and `User` patient.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! The architecture is not for me to decide at the moment but I'll look into that. As for the code, that certainly would work, but unfortunately my end goal would be to search for appointments for a certain patient while selectively excluding the ones with certain physicians

Comment: Gotcha. Edited the answer.